# Django raw count column

Tags: django, ajax, count

Im been confused when I tried to count the append paid_count the error says `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'`. In my query navicat it runs fine like the image below , the only problem is when I count the specific  attribute in my database `count(paid)`. It would be great if anybody could figure out where I am doing something wrong. thank you so much in advance.

[image]

```
 for p in Person.objects.raw('SELECT id,paid, category, category_status, count(paid) FROM app_person WHERE paid_by != "" GROUP BY paid_by, paid, category, category_status ORDER BY paid_by,paid'):
     rpts_paid.append(p.paid)
     rpts_paid_by.append(p.paid_by)
     rpts_category.append(p.category)
        
     rpts_paid_count.append(p.paid).count()  #Error
     reports = {'paymaster_list':rpts_paid_by,'rpts_paid':rpts_paid, 'rpts_category':rpts_category}
    
    return JsonResponse(totals)
```

Comment: You can use Django ORM to group by https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/, other than that your SQL query does not map cleanly to mode so you should use following https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly. This line makes no sense  rpts_paid_count.append(p.paid).count()

Comment: @iklinac thanks for your response, but what does the self means? `def my_custom_sql(self):`